# Youtube full iframe player with no cookies - Can it be done?

Tags: iframe, cookies, youtube

I am trying to create a page with a standard youtube iframe player. It will play a video and when the first video finishes, it will use loadVideoById to load and play a second, and then after it finishes a third video.

The problem I have is that since I have partially watched the second (and third) video while signed into my youtube account, when the second (and third) video plays, it picks up from where I left off watching it on youtube, instead of starting from the beginning, and I don't want this to happen to anyone else who visits the site.

If I open the page in an incognito window it works as expected, so I know my code is good.  If I just use an iframe and embed the video using youtube-nocookie.com as the domain (instead of just youtube.com) the videos start from the beginning.  I could get away with using this method except I can seem to detect when the first video ends so I can change the iframe's source to start the next video.

I'm looking for any advice on either being able to detect when a youtube video ends in an iframe, or a way of using the full player with no cookies, or something (anything) else that will accomplish this task.

Comment: I was able to figure out how to use the full iframe player with no cookies. I was letting the api create the iframe which defaulted to a youtube.com domain in the source tag.When I manually created the iframe with a youtube-nocookie.com domain, it worked and as each new video loaded it kept the youtube-nocookie.com doamin intact, which solved my problem.

Comment: youtube-nocookie.com still drops cookies onto the browser; it just waits until playback is started to do so.