# How to embed a Youtube iframe with cookie consent control?

Tags: iframe, cookies, youtube, youtube-api

I've just discovered that Youtube iframes store cookies on users browsers when they play a video and that for GDPR I need to add some form of consent so visitors can decline.

How do I load Youtube videos without cookies? I've read that changing https://www.youtube.com to https://www.youtube-nocookie.com does the trick but this hasn't done anything for me...

Comment: You can try the solution in this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48256299/youtube-full-iframe-player-with-no-cookies-can-it-be-done) which is to "create the iframe with a youtube-nocookie.com domain. Each new video loaded will keep the youtube-nocookie.com domain intact".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We're going through this very exercise. The only difference between using youtube.com and youtube-nocookie.com (aka privacy-enhanced mode) for your embeds is that youtube-nocookie.com waits until the user starts playing the video before dropping the cookie onto the user's browser.

Comment: Is there any documentation you can refer us to @Eccentropy? For me the cookie is saved but without any information to track the user when using the youtube-nocookie.com domain,